# Best way to drywall a basement

Tags: basement

My basement is dry.  I just recently drylocked the walls.  So now I want to put drywall up.  Was going to use the foam board installation....wooden framing and green board.

But with reading the many opinions....wooden framing in the basement is a no-no.  Metal framing instead?   Do I put up a vapor barrier?  Some says yes....some say no

Comment: Is your question about framing, drywall, or vapor barriers? Please simplify and clarify. As it is, your question is off-topic as too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why some would say no to wood frame, I have done this for years if the basement is dry. Remember if this is a living space it will require outlets every 12' or no space further than 6' from a outlet excluding doorway spaces. 
I put 2x4's flat on the wall , I run the power to junction boxes in the ceiling and drop 1 wire to the shallow outlet boxes because there is not enough room in a shallow box for more than 1 wire and 1 outlet. I think this looks much better than surface mounted in conduit and it is cheaper. I would not add a vapor barrier it would trap any moisture in the wall and insulation possibly creating a mold breeding ground.

Comment: +1 to the "no vapor barrier" let the basement wall breathe and do not risk trapping moisture inside the wall.